# Overriding argparse.Action method in argparse module

Tags: python, argparse

How do i achieve the following command by overriding argpase.Action method.(overriding `__call__()` method)

```
python program.py --delete --file filename
```

Answer (score 0):

With this definition:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--delete', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--file') # default 'store' action
```

your input should produce `args` that looks like:

```
namespace(delete=True, file='filename')
```

It's up to your code to make use of the boolean `args.delete` and the string `args.file`.

The argparse documentation discusses writing a custom `Action` class, but I don't think you need to do that here.  Remember, the primary task of the parser is parsing, figuring out what the user wants in the command line.  It is not the executer.  It does not act on that information.

Comment: But this works even if we give file name before delete argument. but i dont want in such fashion. I need delete to be given first and then file name. How can i do that?

Comment: Yes, flagged arguments like this can occur in any order; that's a design feature of `argparse`.  Look at subparsers in the docs to see how to implement `python prog.py delete --file filename`, where `delete` is understood to be a 'command', as opposed to a True/False parameter.